# Why won't OpenCV show an image stored in a numpy array? (Python)

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, opencv

I read in an image using cv2.imread to a variable and use cv2.imshow to display it just fine. I take the same variable and pass it into a numpy array of the same shape as the image and try to display it. Same shape, same data type and same values in the array and I get a blank, white square from cv2.imshow. Why not the image?

If I take the numpy array and save it using cv2.imwrite it saves the picture just fine. Any help appreciated, this has been driving me crazy.

```
images = np.zeros(shape=(1,30,30,3))

i = 1
a = cv2.resize(cv2.imread('/media/images/'+str(i)+'.png', 1), (30,30))

b = images[0] = a

print(b.shape, images[0].shape)
print(type(b), type(images[0]))

# Displays image
cv2.imshow('img', b)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

# Displays blank, white image
cv2.imshow('img', images[0])
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`b` and `images` don't have the same dtype:

```
>>> images[0].dtype
dtype('float64')
>>> b.dtype
dtype('uint8')
```

So cv2 doesn't know how to color `images`.

So if your first line is:

```
images = np.zeros(shape=(1,30,30,3), dtype=np.uint8)
```

it should fix the problem.

Comment: Lifesaver, thank you so much. Didn't realise the data types were different by default. Thought the floats would have had decimal places when I printed the elements of the array but they just both looked like ints. Thanks again!

Comment: As you can see, I did the tests in the interpreter (typing `b` instead of `print(b)`). It displayed both the dots and dtypes. If find the interpreter is always a time-saver in these crazy situations.